# regex ignoring any line that starts with ;

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
\bG0|G1|(?:[Xx](-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|[Yy](-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|[Zz](-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|[Ee](-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|[Ff](-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?))\b
```

I am struggeling to get my regex to ignore any line that starts with the `;`-symbol or that doesnt start with `G1` or `G0`. while keeping the current ruling intact.

to be clear:

```
; G1 X1 Y2 Z3 -> Should be ignored
X1 Y2 Z3 -> Should be ignored
G1 X1 Y2 Z3 -> Should be a match
G0 X1 Y2 E2000 -> should be a match
```

I have the following demo set-up:

https://regex101.com/r/omsmT1/1

Comment: Which language rsp. regex-flavour? Assuming pcre `\b` at beginning and end make no sense, if this are truly lines replace them with '^' and '$' (beginning/end of line) - then replace `G0|G1|` with `G[01]|` (so `^G[01]|...))$` )

Comment: It's not clear what you want the rest of the rule to do.  Are you trying to match the whole line? Or just the first word (after the G[01])?  To make it only match lines that start with G0 or G1 (effectively what you asked for), just start the regex with "^(?:G[01])".

Answer (score 0):

Since all you care about is the text captured into the groups, you can match the lines that either start with `;` or that do not start with `G0` or `G1` using

```
(?mi)^(?:;|(?!G[01])).*|\b(?:x(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|y(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|z(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|e(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|f(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?))\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/omsmT1/2).

Note the `i` modifier makes the pattern case insensitive, `m` makes `^` match start of any line.

The `^(?:;|(?!G[01])).*` part matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:;|(?!G[01]))` - either

  - `;` - a semi-colon
  - `|` - or
  - `(?!G[01])` - the next two chars must not be `G0` or `G1`
- `.*` - the rest of the string